# How I get data from intent in onRequestPermissionsResult when permission is granted

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, imageview, uri

I want to open an image from storage. If the app runs for the first time and I accept permission then it crashes because it cannot get the uri information for the image to be displayed. How I can get uri information about the Image I selected?

```
if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                imgLogo.setImageBitmap(null);

                Uri orgUri,uriFromPath;
                String convertedPath;
                //Uri return from external activity
                orgUri = data.getData();
                //path converted from Uri
                convertedPath = getRealPathFromURI(orgUri);
                //Uri convert back again from path
                uriFromPath = Uri.fromFile(new File(convertedPath));
                try {
                    Bitmap image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uriFromPath);
                    imgLogo.setImageBitmap(image);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Permission", "Denied");
            }
```

Comment: Your code shown above will fail on most Android devices. A `Uri` is not a file, and `MediaStore` does not have to know about any particular `Uri`. In your case, use an image-loading library like Picasso to populate your `ImageView`. If you insist upon doing it yourself, use a background thread, a `ContentResolver`, `openInputStream()`, `BitmapFactory`, and `decodeStream()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onRequestPermissionsResult()` callback will only have data about your permissions granting results. For the image data you have to obtain it from `onActivityResult()` callback.

Comment: So I need to start something like startActivityForResult(my_intent, IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST) when permission is granted?

Comment: @user2629955 Yes. And then retrieve the image Uri in the `onActivityResult()` `Intent`.

Comment: Is the following correct ? 
my_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
File PictureDir =Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); String PicturePath = PictureDir.getPath();                    Uri data = Uri.parse(PicturePath);                    my_intent.setDataAndType(data, "image/*");                    startActivityForResult(my_intent, IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST);return;

Comment: @user2629955 Yes, that would be one way of doing it